# Is there a correct way to do arbitrarily many nested parentheses? What would come after braces, and after that, etc.?

Tags: parentheses

I know it's poor form to have nested parentheticals, but I want to do it as a kind of joke. What would be the correct way to nest arbitrarily many parentheses in writing? If I wanted to write a whole piece of nested parentheses, where would I go after braces? Surely there can't be an endless list of symbols to go through - there'd have to be a pattern to it at some point, no?

([{...}])?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. There is no proper usage of multi (>3)-nested parentheticals in English, and no need: a restructuring is always to be preferred. ; in maths, repeated fractions are shown using standard brackets on different levels on the page.

Comment: After braces come Invisaligners.

Comment: (You can use (round) brackets (all the way (through))).